# SQL Same Colum for differnet date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Look for some assistance. I want to query in one result comparison from one column comparing year results.
I can get it fine with 2 selects as follows, but not one. ANy thoughts?

---

```
 DECLARE @CYBeginDate datetime
 , @CYEndDate datetime
 , @LYBeginDate datetime
 , @LYEndDate datetime
 , @2YBeginDate datetime
 , @2YEndDate datetime 
 
select @CYBeginDate = dateadd(year, datepart(year, getdate()) - 1900, '1900-07-01') 
select @CYEndDate = dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 12, @CYBeginDate)) 
select @LYBeginDate = dateadd(year, -1, @CYBeginDate) 
select @LYEndDate = dateadd(year, -1, @CYEndDate) 
select @2YBeginDate = dateadd(year, -2, @CYBeginDate) 
select @2YEndDate = dateadd(year, -2, @CYEndDate) 

Select ClientName, ClassOfRiskname, SUM([GrossEarningsNetGST]) AS 'This Year Earnings', NUll 
from Reports_Policy_Transactions  
where EffectiveDate between @CYBeginDate and @CYEndDate 
AND ClientId = 77942 
Group By ClientName, ClassOfRiskname

Select Null, Null, Null, SUM([GrossEarningsNetGST]) AS 'Last Year Earnings' 
from Reports_Policy_Transactions  
where EffectiveDate between @LYBeginDate and @LYEndDate 
AND ClientId = 77942 
Group By ClientName, ClassOfRiskname
```

Comment: also please always provide sample data and desired output sample, thanks

Comment: Please add an explanation as to _what_ you expect your query to do and why you need it in one query.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what does second select mean by all null values , but here is how you can merge two queries, but it really depends on your data , It might not work for your data and you might still need to keep where clause with dates and combine them using `or`

```
Select ClientName
    , ClassOfRiskname
    , SUM(case when EffectiveDate between @LYBeginDate and @LYEndDate then [GrossEarningsNetGST] else 0 end ) AS 'This Year Earnings'
    , SUM(case when  EffectiveDate between @CYBeginDate and @CYEndDate then [GrossEarningsNetGST] else 0 end ) AS 'Last Year Earnings' 
from Reports_Policy_Transactions  
where ClientId = 77942 
Group By ClientName, ClassOfRiskname
```